# Why does iPad preview use wrong image?

Tags: xcode6, image-size, size-classes

My question is, why does the iPad preview use a different image than the storyboard for wRegular hAny?

I'm trying to set up a universal app with a menu that will use larger buttons for iPad.  In the asset catalog, I've specified the standard image size for wAny x hAny, and loaded a larger image for wRegular x hAny.

The story board looks fine for all size classes, with the wRegular x hAny using the iPad image, and everything else using the iPhone image. But the previews all use the iPhone image, including the iPad preview, despite the storyboards showing the correct images.  In the screen shots below, the story board is shown to the left, preview to the right.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  I'm trying to avoid using explicit image sizes for each class - is that what I should be doing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've read everything I can on using different image sizes, and still cannot figure this out.

[image]
[image: wRegular h Any]
[image: wCompact hAny]
[image: wAny hAny]

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a different images by size class for the same button in Interface Builder.  It looks to me like you set the image of the button to be the iPad one first in Regular/Any, then set the iPhone one afterward in Any/Any which changed what you did in Regular/Any.

In this image, see how the Font has a + symbol to the left of it, but Image doesn't?  That's for specifying the value per size class.  Since Image doesn't have that, it's not a value saved for the specific size class.

[image]